# Model is not deployed and cannot predit

Tags: google-cloud-automl, google-cloud-automl-nl

On Google Cloud Automl - Language Classification, I put in the following request for prediction.

I am getting - The model is not deployed, hence not supported for prediction yet.

How do we deploy a model ? I do not see any documentation if deploying a model

I am running this command shown in code in Google Cloud Shell

curl -X POST   -H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token)"   -H "Content-Type: application/json"   https://automl.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/[projectid]/locations/us-central1/models/[Modelname]:predict   -d '{
        "payload" : {
          "textSnippet": {
               "content": "YOUR TEXT HERE",
                "mime_type": "text/plain"
           },
        }
      }'
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "The model is not deployed, hence not supported for prediction yet.",
    "status": "FAILED_PRECONDITION"
  }
}

Expected prediction

Answer (score 1):

You can deploy a successfully trained model using the UI on GCP. 
Under HOME go to your respective AI and find your model in its dashboard.